# How did Karen's little sister's spirit get fused to Karen?

Tags: karen-senki

I have watched the 11 episodes and wonder if I missed the point where they explained how Karen's little sister, Touka's spirit became fused with Karen.

Comment: It seems it's not explained at all anywhere? [THEM Anime's review](https://www.themanime.org/viewreview.php?id=1741) has same opinion with you: "*Now she (Touka)'s somehow- through the gun, through Karen's body energy, or through yet again reaching into that forbidden source of arbitrary inspiration, we don't know- **somehow** brought back as an energy-entity that delights in destroying robots*"